Is it necessary to use vacuum insulated pipe for filling LOX in the rocket tanks
Is there really need of vacuum insulated pipes on launching pad for LOX? What insulation and pipe dia are used from LOX storage to the launch tank at what flow rate and pressure, please?..

For what vehicle are you asking about? Also consider accepting some answers to your other questions.

Are you building a lox motor lmao

please note that if you are trying to build your own rocket motor, questions regarding that are explicitly off-topic

Well. This a general question and not particularly related to any vehicle.because I read a Research paper where it was quoted that vacuum insulated pipes used for transportation of LOX from storage to launching pad. Obviously it t will be long length and dia. How is it possible to make  it vacuum insulated?

Comments on this forum also say that LOX feed lines do not have any insulation over it. So mean vacuum insulated feed lines or else?

Are you asking if there are installations that use insulation and other than use vacuum? Regarding a vacuum design, a thermos bottle does not have any insulation other than a vacuum, and it works well to keep the contents cold (or hot).

If there are comments on this stack (not forum) that say LOX lines are not insulated, I have counterexamples for you. And you are asking for specific pipe diameters and flow rates. That obviously will vary from one vehicle / launch pad to another. If you want some examples, that can be done.

I've heard that it's preferred not to use insulation on your lox lines so you can see where & if you've got leaks.

@AntonHengst I can see that depending on the installation. If launch pad 39 had not insulated their 1400 feet of pipe in Florida, I doubt they would have had very good quality propellant coming out the end. I tried to point out that the answer to this is very installation and vehicle dependent.

Some example numbers for the space shuttle.
The LO2 loading pipes at the shuttle launch pads were insulated by means of vacuum jackets. (as were the feedlines in the orbiter)

...a new 8-inch diameter vacuum-jacketed fill line is required...The present fill line is a 6-inch vacuum-jacketed line about 1400 feet in length.

Source: Booster Systems Briefs, pdf page 245
This picture shows the distance from the LO2 storage sphere to the launch pad.

Source: What happened to boiled-off gases from the storage tanks at Launch Complex 39?
LO2 flowrates during loading of the shuttle External Tank varied but maxed out at 1400 gallons per minute. Delta p was up to 55 psi.

Source: USA training documents, personal notes. Annotations mine.
Note on the units: these are historical documents, use some perspective.

Thanks and so nice
